# Make a new column in a data frame containing text extracted from another based on a list or vector

Tags: r, string, dataframe, tidyverse

I have an R data frame containing a text string column. I want to add a new column where a word matches a string and put that string into it.  I understand how to do this for one specific text target as in the reproduceable example below:

```
#make a data frame
library(tidyverse)
d=c("Buy apples here","Pears are cheap","Oranges for sale", "Potatoes are not fruit")
df<-as.data.frame(d)

#extract 'Orange' into a new column called 'fruit'
df<-df%>%mutate(fruit = str_extract(d, "Orange"))
```

However, how do I vectorise this by using a list of words as my targets?

```
#target words
f=c("orange", "apple","pear")
dfa<-as.data.frame(f)
```

And how do I ignore the case so I get a result set so 'apple' and 'Orange' both produce a match and have the correct fruit description put into the new column:

```
#desired output 
f1=c("apple","pear","orange","<NA>")
dfb<-as.data.frame(cbind(d,f1))
dfb
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a regex from your vector of strings to be matched, pasting them together and seperating each by the pipe operator  `|`. You can eliminate case as a concern by converting both `d` and `f` to uppercase (or lowercase) during the matching:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(fruit = str_extract(toupper(d), 
                             toupper(paste(unique(dfa$f), collapse = "|"))))
#>                        d  fruit
#> 1        Buy apples here  APPLE
#> 2        Pears are cheap   PEAR
#> 3       Oranges for sale ORANGE
#> 4 Potatoes are not fruit   <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks Allan, this works perfectly.  I'd not appreciated how flexible and simple mutate can be here in performing the lookup.

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can use `regmatches/regexpr`

```
v1 <- regexpr(toupper(paste(unique(dfa$f), collapse = "|")), toupper(d))
out <- character(length(d))
out[v1 >0] <- regmatches(toupper(d), v1)
out
#[1] "APPLE"  "PEAR"   "ORANGE" ""
```

Comment: Also a useful answer.  I'd accept both if I could, but have upvoted this. I need to cbind the output into my df to get the desired output. Thanks for your help.